# JavaScript does not work after you add new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-draggable

JavaScript does not work after you add new elements ?
add more later, but I want you to work for elements how to track down a road I do not know
Example;

```
$(".ui-draggable").draggable();    
$('body').append('<div class="ui-draggable"></div>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `.draggable()` is not dynamic.

Do this:

```
$(".ui-draggable").draggable();    
$('body').append($('<div class="ui-draggable"></div>').draggable());
```

Your first line attaches only the elements which were present in the DOM.

It will not check for dynamically added ones.